# Why my app stop working?

Tags: android, android-service

I am developing a simple app that just play a white noise sound in background while I am doing other things.

It works very well when I switch to other apps ( like games, chrome browser, etc ) but sometimes ( for example when there are many chrome tab opened ) the white noise sound stop and I need to reload my app.

I am NOT using Services, is this the reason ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because your apps is getting killed by the system to give up resources for to other apps (games, chrome, etc). So you need to use a **Service**.

Here an excerpt from [Processes and Application Life Cycle](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/processes/process-lifecycle.html)
 for more details explanation:

> An unusual and fundamental feature of Android is that an application
>   process's lifetime is not directly controlled by the application
>   itself. Instead, it is determined by the system through a combination
>   of the parts of the application that the system knows are running, how
>   important these things are to the user, and how much overall memory is
>   available in the system.
>
> ...
>
> 4. A **cached process** is one that is not currently needed, so the system is free to kill it as desired when memory is needed elsewhere. In a
>      normally behaving system, these are the only processes involved in
>      memory management: a well running system will have multiple cached
>      processes always available (for more efficient switching between
>      applications) and regularly kill the oldest ones as needed. Only in
>      very critical (and undesirable) situations will the system get to a
>      point where all cached processes are killed and it must start killing
>      service processes.   These processes often hold one or more Activity
>      instances that are not currently visible to the user (the onStop()
>      method has been called and returned). Provided they implement their
>      Activity life-cycle correctly (see Activity for more details), when
>      the system kills such processes it will not impact the user's
>      experience when returning to that app: it can restore the previously
>      saved state when the associated activity is recreated in a new
>      process.

Answer (score 2):

I think [Services](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) is What You are looking For.

> A Service is an application component that can perform long-running
>   operations in the background, and it does not provide a user
>   interface.

Answer (score 2):

For better chance of preventing OS to kill your app, you should use a

> Foreground Service

following the official guide here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html#Foreground

Remember that there is no way to be certain that OS will never kill your app, because when RAM becomes really low it could kill every process indipendently from type, following his priority rules